# Gearman writing "Too many open files" into the log. Disk space issues

Tags: filesystems, mongodb, node.js, disk-space-utilization

We're running a service that makes screenshots of URL supplied and posts it to our S3 bucket. Similar to [manet](https://github.com/vbauer/manet), but our custom coded nodejs app. We don't store the screenshots on our local hard drive. We store them temporary for resize, then delete. The temp image folder is always empty.

The problem is: disk space is running lower and lower until server restart. For example, now `df -h` shows:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-94:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      118G   74G   40G  65% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            7.4G  8.0K  7.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.5G  360K  1.5G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

However, `du -sh /` shows:

```
root@ip-10-0-1-94:~# du -sh /
du: cannot access ‘/proc/14440’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/14520/task/14520/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/14520/task/14520/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/14520/fd/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/14520/fdinfo/4’: No such file or directory
du: cannot access ‘/proc/14521’: No such file or directory
7.0G    /
```

If I do `du` for all folders in root filesystem, it will sum up to 7 Gb, not 74. If I restart the server, once it's back up again, there will be 7 Gb as it should be, but in 10-12 hours 70+ again and counting.

We're using `mongodb` as our storage , so I'm assuming it can be it, however, I removed `smallfiles` config option that I placed earlier. Still the same thing.

Attaching `lsof` output [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/df165ddfed8a69cb7383) and `ps aux` [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e0c2423f234689cb7279)

Here is `mount` output:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-94:~$ mount
/dev/xvda1 on / type ext4 (rw,discard)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (rw)
none on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,size=10%,mode=0755)
none on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=5242880)
none on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /run/user type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,size=104857600,mode=0755)
none on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw)
systemd on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,none,name=systemd)
```

Restarting any of running services, like `mongodb` or `supervisor` doesn't change anything. Here is an example:

```
root@ip-10-0-1-94:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      118G   74G   40G  65% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            7.4G  8.0K  7.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.5G  360K  1.5G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
root@ip-10-0-1-94:~# service mongod restart
mongod stop/waiting
mongod start/running, process 31590
root@ip-10-0-1-94:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      118G   74G   40G  65% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            7.4G  8.0K  7.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.5G  360K  1.5G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

or `supervisor` controlling `node` processes (workers and application) :

```
root@ip-10-0-1-94:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      118G   74G   40G  65% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            7.4G  8.0K  7.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.5G  360K  1.5G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
root@ip-10-0-1-94:~# service supervisor restart
Restarting supervisor: supervisord.
root@ip-10-0-1-94:~# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      118G   74G   40G  65% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            7.4G  8.0K  7.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           1.5G  360K  1.5G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            7.4G     0  7.4G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

**UPDATE**: as it turns out this happens because of `gearman` log with tons of

```
accept(Too many open files) -> libgearman-server/gearmand.cc:851
```

messages. Even though the file is deleted, it's still open by the gearman processes and therefore the space is not released. This is the proof:

```
root@ip-10-0-1-94:~# sudo lsof -s | awk '$5 == "REG"' | sort -n -r -k 7,7 | head -n 1
gearmand   4221           gearman    3w      REG              202,1 31748949650     143608 /var/log/gearman-job-server/gearman.log.1 (deleted)
```

(thanks to @Andrew Henle)

Now the next question is: why does `gearman` write that to the log. As stated [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gearman/NnGlRdYQeDM) it's because of too many connections to `gearman` in `TIME_WAIT` state
However, they are not in `TIME_WAIT`, they are in `ESTABLISHED`. [Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e8d7037841e8b5fa1482) they are.

If I do `strace -p 4221`, I'm seeing only this

```
write(22, "\3", 1)                      = 1
epoll_wait(6, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}}, 32, -1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {169649, 568914324}) = 0
gettimeofday({1446109467, 793708}, NULL) = 0
accept4(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33010), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 874
write(17, "\3", 1)                      = 1
epoll_wait(6, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}}, 32, -1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {169659, 749954206}) = 0
gettimeofday({1446109477, 974726}, NULL) = 0
accept4(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33060), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 875
write(32, "\3", 1)                      = 1
epoll_wait(6, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}}, 32, -1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {169659, 754505349}) = 0
gettimeofday({1446109477, 979307}, NULL) = 0
accept4(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33062), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 876
write(27, "\3", 1)                      = 1
epoll_wait(6, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}}, 32, -1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {169664, 300399805}) = 0
gettimeofday({1446109482, 525209}, NULL) = 0
accept4(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33134), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 877
write(22, "\3", 1)                      = 1
epoll_wait(6, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}}, 32, -1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {169666, 161035104}) = 0
gettimeofday({1446109484, 385826}, NULL) = 0
accept4(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33165), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 878
write(17, "\3", 1)                      = 1
epoll_wait(6, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}}, 32, -1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {169668, 308112847}) = 0
gettimeofday({1446109486, 532900}, NULL) = 0
accept4(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33186), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 879
write(32, "\3", 1)                      = 1
epoll_wait(6, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}}, 32, -1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {169671, 251265264}) = 0
gettimeofday({1446109489, 476077}, NULL) = 0
accept4(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33218), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 880
write(27, "\3", 1)                      = 1
epoll_wait(6, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}}, 32, -1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {169672, 320483648}) = 0
gettimeofday({1446109490, 545274}, NULL) = 0
accept4(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33232), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 881
write(22, "\3", 1)                      = 1
epoll_wait(6, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}}, 32, -1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {169676, 186686282}) = 0
gettimeofday({1446109494, 411486}, NULL) = 0
accept4(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33303), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 882
write(17, "\3", 1)                      = 1
epoll_wait(6, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}}, 32, -1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {169684, 699748557}) = 0
gettimeofday({1446109502, 924549}, NULL) = 0
accept4(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33320), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 883
write(32, "\3", 1)                      = 1
epoll_wait(6, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}}, 32, -1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {169687, 906830251}) = 0
gettimeofday({1446109506, 131601}, NULL) = 0
accept4(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33348), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 884
write(27, "\3", 1)                      = 1
epoll_wait(6, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}}, 32, -1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {169701, 112588731}) = 0
gettimeofday({1446109519, 337387}, NULL) = 0
accept4(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33386), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 885
write(22, "\3", 1)                      = 1
epoll_wait(6, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}}, 32, -1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {169707, 686312787}) = 0
gettimeofday({1446109525, 911113}, NULL) = 0
accept4(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33420), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 886
write(17, "\3", 1)                      = 1
```

each portion of

```
epoll_wait(6, {{EPOLLIN, {u32=9, u64=9}}}, 32, -1) = 1
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {169707, 686312787}) = 0
gettimeofday({1446109525, 911113}, NULL) = 0
accept4(9, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(33420), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, [16], SOCK_NONBLOCK) = 886
write(17, "\3", 1)
```

is added every 3-5 seconds. Nothing else for a few minutes.

Comment: What filesystem are you using?

Comment: ext4. Will update my question now with `mount` output

Comment: Does the disk space re-appear if you just restart Mongo?

Comment: forgot to say: no, it doesn't. Restarting mongodb, node doesn't change anything in space allocated. Will update my question now

Comment: Rebooting the server change anything, freeing some disk space?

Answer (score 2):

Whatever process creates this file is your culprit:

```
gearmand 811 gearman 3w REG 202,1 71016771760 143618 /var/log/gearman-job-server/gearman.log.1 (deleted)
```

Given that it's called `gearman.log.1`, I suspect that whatever is doing log rollover isn't doing it properly.

When you see a gross mismatch between `df` and `du` like you're seeing, it's usually a deleted file that a process still has open.  `lsof | grep deleted` works well on Linux to find them.

Simply searching for `deleted` in your posted `lsof` output shows several other `*.1` log files that seem to have the same improper rollover issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps! It's really that file. See my updated question (below UPDATE). Now the question is in `gearman` and why does it have too many files opened.

Answer (score 1):

Just another information about CentOS.
In this case, when using "systemctl" to launch process.
You have to modify the system file ==> /usr/lib/systemd/system/processName.service
.Had this line in the file :

```
LimitNOFILE=50000
```

And just reload your system conf :

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```